# Actionscript 3: gotoAndStop

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript, frame

I have a project in Flash CS3 that's giving me a bit of trouble. I have a movieclip, and in that movieclip, I have a button. The movieclip is named *bg* and the button *tohallway_btn*. My coding is on the stage on a layer, not on classes or in a package, or anything of that sort. This is my coding:

```
bg.tohallway_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tohallwayClick);
function tohallwayClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
        gotoAndStop (141);
    }
```

It seems simple enough, yet when I debug and the button is clicked, the flash player freezes over. I have absolutely no idea what's causing it to do this.

I get a type error in output as well:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Camille_fla::MainTimeline/enterF()[Camille_fla.MainTimeline::frame140:130]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What should happen when you click on that button? Should it go to frame 141 on the stage? Or frame 141 in the MovieClip bg?

Comment: Your code and error are unrelated. The error is in a function `enterF()` - can you post that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An onEnterFrame listener was called and not removed that was referencing an object (bg) that was not on the stage after the goto call.

```
function tohallwayClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    **removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterF);**
    gotoAndStop(141);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First make sure your button and your code are on the same frame, they can be on different layers, but make sure they are lined up.

If you want it to go to the frame on your main timeline, or stage, instead of writing:

```
gotoAndStop (141)
```

try:

```
stage.gotoAndStop(141);
```

Comment: I tried that and got: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.

Comment: `Stage` doesn't have a `gotoAndStop()` method.